# How to check whether servlet name exists?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I need to know whether servlet exists or not before forward a request! How I could do this (best way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Servlet 3.0, just check if [`ServletContext#getServletRegistration()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServletRegistration%28java.lang.String%29) don't return `null` for the given servlet name.

If you're not on Servlet 3.0 yet, parse the `web.xml` yourself.

That said, this is a rather strange requirement. Is the servlet added dynamically/programmatically based on some condition or so? It'd probably be more easier to check exactly that condition before forwarding.